# C# Regex Having Unexpected Results

Tags: c#, regex

I have a Regex that is supposed to match an "S" that is by itself within a string. I have used the following version and it works by rejecting the string "Saint Charles":

```
regex = new Regex(@"(^|\s)(?<stuff>S?)(\s|$)");
Match match = regex.Match("Saint Charles");
```

The match fails as expected.

My question is how come the second version below accepts the string:

```
regex = new Regex(@"(^|\b)(?<stuff>S?)(\b|$)");
Match match = regex.Match("Saint Charles");
```

The match succeeds, but I expected it to fail.

**UPDATE:**
Here's some background on what I'm aiming for:

I have a list of locations that are either wrongly spelled or require different wording:

```
string[] locationNames =
            {
                "Ponte Vedra Beac",
                "Newton Upper Fal",
                "Howey In The Hil",
                "Mc Donough",
                "East Mc Dowell",
                "Saint Charles",
                "Cape Saint Clair",
                "Marine On Saint",
                "W Mifflin Fin",
                "Mt Sylvan",
                "Bromley Mtn",
                "S Richmond Hill"
            };
```

By looking at the data I've determined that some replacements shall occur at the end of the location name, some at the beginning while others anywhere in between.

I'm using a dictionary to determine 1) The correct replacement and 2) The type of regex required.

```
var alternateSpellings = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                                {
                                    {"Beac$", "Beach"},
                                    {"Fal$", "Falls"},
                                    {"Hil$", "Hills"},
                                    {"Mc ", "Mc"},
                                    {"\bMt\b", "Mount"},
                                    {"\bMtn\b", "Mountain"},
                                    {"\bS\b", "South"},
                                    {"\bSaint\b", "St."}

                                };
```

I loop through the list and depending on the embedded meta-character pick a regex. The options are:

```
regex = new Regex(".*(?<stuff>" + alternateSpelling.Key.Replace("$", "") + ")$");
```

OR

```
regex = new Regex(@"(^|\s)(?<stuff>" + alternateSpelling.Key.Replace("\b", "") + @")(\s|$)");
```

NOTE: I have dropped the `\b` in favour of `\s`
OR

```
regex = new Regex(".*(?<stuff>" + alternateSpelling.Key + ").*");
```

Once I've found a match I do the replace...

```
if (match.Success)
                {
                    var stuff = match.Groups["stuff"].Value;
                    var stuffPosition = match.Groups["stuff"].Index;

                    newLocationName = locationName.Remove(stuffPosition, stuff.Length).Insert(stuffPosition, alternateSpelling.Value);

                }
```

Comment: Just wondering if you can't use something more direct instead of a regex here.

Comment: I don't think you can match on `\b` - it's an anchor similar to `^` and `$` rather than a character class

Comment: @Mihai The code snippet is just a small bit of a much bigger function and the characters/words being matched are dynamic with different rules of positioning within the input string.

Comment: @arco444 Does it therefore mean `(^|\b)` is wrong?

Comment: Neither of these regexes matches "*an S that is by itself within a string*". Both of them will succeed on the string `" piglet"`, for example.

Comment: What is the result that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R From your answer below I realized that the "?" after "S" was out of place. The S is not meant to be optional. Regex gives me a headache.

Comment: If you remove the `S` strings/words which only contain `S` would match. for example http://regex101.com/r/aF9hH5/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How `(^|\b)(?<stuff>S?)(\b|$)`  matches `Saint Charles`

```
^      =>   Start of String
             Saint Charles
            ^

S?     =>    which is optional. Tries to match

             Saint Charles
             ^

(\b|$) =>    Tries for \b or $ after S. But cannot match. Backtracks to start

             Saint Charles
            ^
\b     =>    Matches at the start of the string

             Saint Charles 
             ^
```

Hence success

- `\b` matches word boundaries. That is at the start and end of string

**How to correct**

To match words that contain only `S` simple modification by droping the `?` would help

```
(^|\b)(?<stuff>S)(\b|$)
```

[**Regex Example**](http://regex101.com/r/aF9hH5/2)

Comment: @KalenGi Glad to hear that i was of some help :)

Answer (score 2):

S? matches the S zero or one times. Hence there is a match at the start of the string, which is

```
(start of string)(zero occurrences of S)(word boundary)
```

Try just S instead of S?

Answer (score 0):

[**Word Boundaries on MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#WordBoundary)

> The \b anchor specifies that the match must occur on a boundary
>   between a **word character (the \w language element) and a non-word
>   character (the \W language element)**. Word characters consist of
>   alphanumeric characters and underscores; a non-word character is any
>   character that is not alphanumeric or an underscore. (For more
>   information, see Character Classes in Regular Expressions.) **The match
>   may also occur on a word boundary at the beginning or end of the
>   string.**

<sub>*Emphasis is my answer.</sub>